# Object Table is dependent on Column ID - Code First

Tags: c#, database, ef-code-first, asp.net-mvc-5

I've been trying to get this database set up and I have not a clue what the problem is. I've searched and searched but nothing is helping. Here is what I'm trying to do:

Question.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace ProjectCrux.Models
{
    public class Question
    {
        public int questionId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Question")]
        public string question { get; set; }

        public int studentID { get; set; }  // FK
        public int hashtagLinksID { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
        public virtual QuestionLinkToHashtag HashtagLinks { get; set; }

        public virtual Student Student { get; set; }

    }
}
```

QuestionLinkToHashtag.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace ProjectCrux.Models
{
    public class QuestionLinkToHashtag
    {
        public int questionLinkToHashtagId { get; set; }

        public int questionId { get; set; } //FK to question

        public int hashtagsId { get; set; } //FK to hashtag


        public virtual Question question { get; set; }

        public virtual Hashtag hashtags { get; set; }
    }
}
```

ProjectCruxContext.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace ProjectCrux.Models
{
    public class ProjectCruxContext : DbContext
    {
        public ProjectCruxContext()
            : base("name=DefaultConnection")
        {

        }
        public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Question> Questions { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
        public DbSet<QuestionLinkToHashtag> QuestionLinkToHashtags { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Hashtag> Hashtags { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Question>().HasRequired(x => x.HashtagLinks)
               .WithMany();

            modelBuilder.Entity<QuestionLinkToHashtag>().HasRequired(x => x.question)
               .WithMany()
               .HasForeignKey(x => x.questionId);

            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
    }
}
```

basically we're trying to implement a hashtag system very similar to overflow's. this is the error I'm getting when run the update-database command:

The object 'PK_dbo.QuestionLinkToHashtags' is dependent on column 'questionLinkToHashtagId'.
ALTER TABLE DROP COLUMN questionLinkToHashtagId failed because one or more objects access this column.

I have no idea how to work around this. We are using code first and all the help I've been able to find are messing with the database itself and I don't understand that one bit. Could anyone possibly explain what the problem is, why its happening, and how to fix it? Or point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Latest Add-Migration

```
namespace ProjectCrux.Migrations
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;

    public partial class QuestinHashtagUpdate1 : DbMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
            DropForeignKey("dbo.QuestionLinkToHashtags", "questionId", "dbo.Questions");
            DropForeignKey("dbo.Hashtags", "QuestionLinkToHashtag_questionLinkToHashtagId", "dbo.QuestionLinkToHashtags");
            DropIndex("dbo.QuestionLinkToHashtags", new[] { "questionId" });
            DropIndex("dbo.Hashtags", new[] { "QuestionLinkToHashtag_questionLinkToHashtagId" });
            DropColumn("dbo.QuestionLinkToHashtags", "questionLinkToHashtagId");
            DropColumn("dbo.QuestionLinkToHashtags", "hashtagId");
            RenameColumn(table: "dbo.QuestionLinkToHashtags", name: "questionId", newName: "questionLinkToHashtagId");
            RenameColumn(table: "dbo.QuestionLinkToHashtags", name: "QuestionLinkToHashtag_questionLinkToHashtagId", newName: "hashtagId");
            DropPrimaryKey("dbo.QuestionLinkToHashtags");
            AlterColumn("dbo.QuestionLinkToHashtags", "questionLinkToHashtagId", c => c.Int(nullable: false));
            AddPrimaryKey("dbo.QuestionLinkToHashtags", "questionLinkToHashtagId");
            CreateIndex("dbo.QuestionLinkToHashtags", "questionLinkToHashtagId");
            CreateIndex("dbo.QuestionLinkToHashtags", "hashtagId");
            AddForeignKey("dbo.QuestionLinkToHashtags", "questionLinkToHashtagId", "dbo.Questions", "questionId");
            AddForeignKey("dbo.QuestionLinkToHashtags", "hashtagId", "dbo.Hashtags", "hashtagId", cascadeDelete: true);
            DropColumn("dbo.Hashtags", "QuestionLinkToHashtag_questionLinkToHashtagId");
        }

        public override void Down()
        {
            AddColumn("dbo.Hashtags", "QuestionLinkToHashtag_questionLinkToHashtagId", c => c.Int());
            DropForeignKey("dbo.QuestionLinkToHashtags", "hashtagId", "dbo.Hashtags");
            DropForeignKey("dbo.QuestionLinkToHashtags", "questionLinkToHashtagId", "dbo.Questions");
            DropIndex("dbo.QuestionLinkToHashtags", new[] { "hashtagId" });
            DropIndex("dbo.QuestionLinkToHashtags", new[] { "questionLinkToHashtagId" });
            DropPrimaryKey("dbo.QuestionLinkToHashtags");
            AlterColumn("dbo.QuestionLinkToHashtags", "questionLinkToHashtagId", c => c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true));
            AddPrimaryKey("dbo.QuestionLinkToHashtags", "questionLinkToHashtagId");
            RenameColumn(table: "dbo.QuestionLinkToHashtags", name: "hashtagId", newName: "QuestionLinkToHashtag_questionLinkToHashtagId");
            RenameColumn(table: "dbo.QuestionLinkToHashtags", name: "questionLinkToHashtagId", newName: "questionId");
            AddColumn("dbo.QuestionLinkToHashtags", "hashtagId", c => c.Int(nullable: false));
            AddColumn("dbo.QuestionLinkToHashtags", "questionLinkToHashtagId", c => c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true));
            CreateIndex("dbo.Hashtags", "QuestionLinkToHashtag_questionLinkToHashtagId");
            CreateIndex("dbo.QuestionLinkToHashtags", "questionId");
            AddForeignKey("dbo.Hashtags", "QuestionLinkToHashtag_questionLinkToHashtagId", "dbo.QuestionLinkToHashtags", "questionLinkToHashtagId");
            AddForeignKey("dbo.QuestionLinkToHashtags", "questionId", "dbo.Questions", "questionId", cascadeDelete: true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you get this when you compile or when you run upgrade-database? If it's when you compile which line gives this error?

Comment: I'm sorry. I should have been more clear. This is when I run the update-database command.

Comment: OK, have a look at your migrations then, one of them is trying to drop the fk column from the table.

Comment: Ok, been fiddling around with it. Unfortunately this makes no sense. Sorry if all of this is really simple, this is my first time working with web design stuff. I added my latest migration to it. I see that it adds a FK and then drops it. I've tried my best to figure out how to fix it, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: This is more of a EF stuff than a web design stuff. It looks like you've renamed one of the FK columns. EF migrations code makes mistakes sometimes too, it's not always perfect. It's bit hard to read here, it looks like it's dropping the column and then renaming it? You have to check the code yourself and see which columns it's dropping and which ones it's renaming but maybe try to remove all drops and creates and just keep the renames and alters. See if that runs and what changes it makes to the DB. Assuming this is test DB you can mess with, not production.